# Minimal IOS version accepted in AppleStore submission?

Tags: iphone, ios, submission

Just to be sure, I want to know if an application targeted for IOS 4.2 could be submitted to apple approval process ?

So the application can be downloaded on iPhone 3G.

thanks for the info.

andré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine, you can support any OS version you want.

It is best to be able to test on each version you support thou

edit: You will need to make sure your project support armv6 and armv7 thou

Comment: Is there any new info on minimal iOS version supported by AppStore submission process? Did it change?

Comment: Not too sure, however you need to make sure your building using the latest SDK as your application must support the iPhone 5/5s